# Update tile image every minute windows 8 app

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, periodic-task

Hi, I need update the image of my tile every minute, but I cannot find any solution. I've looked at [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff) but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

Images in tiles are loaded from web twice but not again after that; How can I update the images in my tile every minute?

For example: [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40039421/tile.png), my tile and numbers are images on a web server and I need to refresh this image every minute with any new images.

```
 public static void CreateSchedule()
    {




        var tileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
        var plannedUpdated = tileUpdater.GetScheduledTileNotifications();


        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime planTill = now.AddHours(4);

        string src1 = "http://mysite/squareLogo128.png";

        DateTime updateTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0).AddMinutes(1);
        if (plannedUpdated.Count > 0)
            updateTime = plannedUpdated.Select(x => x.DeliveryTime.DateTime).Union(new [] { updateTime }).Max();



        string xml = "<tile>"
                         + "<visual>"
                         + "<binding template='TileWideImageAndText01'>"
                         + "<text id='1'>This tile notification uses web images</text>"
                         + "<image id='1' src='" + src1 + "' alt='Web image'/>"
                         + "</binding>"
                         + "<binding template='TileSquareImage'>"
                         + "<image id='1' src='" + src1 + "' alt='Web image'/>"
                         + "</binding>"
                         + "</visual>"
                         + "</tile>";

        XmlDocument documentNow = new XmlDocument();
        documentNow.LoadXml(xml);

        tileUpdater.Update(new TileNotification(documentNow) { ExpirationTime = now.AddMinutes(1) });
        for (var startPlanning = updateTime; startPlanning < planTill; startPlanning = startPlanning.AddMinutes(1))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(startPlanning);
            Debug.WriteLine(planTill);

            try
            {
                string src2 = "http://mysite/squareLogo128.png";
                string xml2 = "<tile>"
                        + "<visual>"
                        + "<binding template='TileWideImageAndText01'>"
                        + "<text id='1'>This tile notification uses web images</text>"
                        + "<image id='1' src='" + src2 + "' alt='Web image'/>"
                        + "</binding>"
                        + "<binding template='TileSquareImage'>"
                        + "<image id='1' src='" + src2 + "' alt='Web image'/>"
                        + "</binding>"
                        + "</visual>"
                        + "</tile>";

                XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                document.LoadXml(xml2);

                ScheduledTileNotification scheduledNotification = new ScheduledTileNotification(document, new DateTimeOffset(startPlanning)) { ExpirationTime = startPlanning.AddMinutes(1) };
                tileUpdater.AddToSchedule(scheduledNotification);


            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just falling out of your `try{}catch{}` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming here that you are seeing the `Debug.WriteLine` output, and you've confirmed you're not swallowing the exception in your empty `catch`.

Have you tried running [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/)?  Since you're requesting the same image over and over, I wonder if it's being served out of a local cache (though why you'd see the right one **twice** is a little mysterious).

If you tack on a random query string, say

```
string src2 = "http://mysite/squareLogo128.png" + "?" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

that might fool the cache (and be a quick test to see if that may be the issue).  If it is though(and it's not something AFAIK you have control over), a better option would be to set response headers on the image retrieval (via a service) that will set an appropriate no-cache header; otherwise, you're filling the caches with never-to-be-reused images.

Take a look at [my blog post on image handling with notifications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/06/windows-8-notifications-image-handling.aspx), particularly the section "Images in the Cloud" for a little more context.